# Can't start Liberty server in debug mode - "agent library failed to init: jdwp"

Tags: websphere-liberty

When I try to start a WebSphere Liberty server in *debug* mode (to connect the Eclipse Java debugger) via:

`$ ./wlp/bin/server debug MyServer`

I get the following error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: jdwp
ERROR: Cannot load this JVM TI agent twice, check your java command line for duplicate jdwp options.
```

and the server doesn't start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The jvm.options contents can collide with the 'debug' subcommand

If the **jvm.options** file already includes options enabling the debugger then use the

`liberty start <server>`

subcommand rather than:

`liberty debug <server>`

E.g. in my case my server had file **.../usr/servers/MyServer/jvm.options** with contents:

```
#Generated by liberty-maven-plugin
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=7777
```

so these options collided with the options triggered by the **debug** subcommand.

#### OR

You can remove the **jvm.options** contents or file and use the **debug** subcommand instead.

**NOTE:** Reading this explanation, the error message becomes clear, but this Q&A is hopefully useful in case it didn't occur to someone that this is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In jvm.options put these entries:

```
-Dwas.debug.mode=true
-Dcom.ibm.websphere.ras.inject.at.transform=true
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=7777
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add an update, jvm.options can also reside in /usr/shared so the same debug options span multiple servers. This would be a bad approach if you're running multiple servers and need to debug them all individually.